# Trouble Casting in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols

I'm pretty new to Swift and am trying to cast a UITableViewCell to a protocol or base cell class I've set up and then use a method on it. For the life of me I can't get the compiler to silence it's warnings, and I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Here's the different approaches I've taken:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell is BaseCell {
            return cell.computeHeight()
        }
    }
```

Gives error: `Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'computerHeight'`

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? BaseCell {
            return cell.computeHeight()
    }
```

Gives a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cell.conformsToProtocol(CellDimensions) {
            return cell.computeHeight()
        }
    }
```

2 errors for that one, first is `Cannot convert value of type (CellDimension).Protocol (aka 'CellDimension.Protocol') to expected argument type 'Protocol'`, second error is the same as the first example's error.

Anyone have any idea how to do this? BaseCell follows the CellDimension protocol, and the cell I'm getting should inherit from BaseCell to allow it to use ComputeHeight, but for some reason I can't get this working for the life of me on Swift. On Objective C this would be trivial but I can't get the syntax right in Swift. I'd appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Please show the declaration of BaseCell and CellDimensions

Comment: The second format is correct.  I suggest you set a breakpoint and step into the code to determine where/why you get the runtime exception.  And yes, please show the declaration of the cell class and the `computeHeight` method.

Comment: You state that `BaseCell` follows CellDimension protocol. BaseCell should be

    `class BaseCell : UICollectionViewCell {}`

As Paul said, your second code in the table view is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your second one is the correct way to downcast:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? BaseCell {
    return cell.computeHeight()
}
```

In that second one, inside the `if` statement, the compile-time type of `cell` is `BaseCell`.

The first one (`if cell is BaseCell`) is an effective check for the `BaseCell` type — the conditional works — but does not actually change the type of the `cell` variable. As the compiler error says, its compile-time type is still `UITableViewCell`.

The third one is just a convoluted variant of the first one.

Why the EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the second one? It’s hard to say without seeing the rest of your code, but it’s not your `as?` cast.

There are two likely possibilities: (1) it’s crashing inside `cell.computeHeight()`, or (2) your `as?` cast fails and it crashes in whatever code comes after.

You could distinguish those possibilities with a few debug statements:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? BaseCell {
    print("-----> cast succeeded; calling computeHeight()")
    return cell.computeHeight()
}
print("-----> cast failed; cell is not BaseCell, but instead is \(cell.dynamicType)")
```